# SQL server calculation

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables as described below

**MonthlyOrder table 4 columns**
CustomerID
DateID (represented in integer and as the first of the month = 20121201)
OrderCount - INT

**HoursSpend Tbale has 4 columns**
CustomerID
DateID
Function - VARCHAR() -- Functions are Reporting, Admini and Sales calls
Hours - INTEGER  -- Hours spent on each function during the month

**Rates Table has 3 columns**
CustomerID
AccountRate -- Money (IF NULL then default is $50)
OperationRates  - Money

The calculation that I need to achieve from this tables are
(LoadCount*AccountRate) + ((Hours for Reporting Function from HoursSpend table + Hours for Amin + Hours for Sales calls) * OperationRates from **Rates** table)

Please advise on the best way to achieve this calculation 
**MonthlyOrder**
CustomerID  DateID  OrderCount
1   20121201    20
1   20121202    10
2   20121210    100
**HoursSpend**
CustomerID  DateID  Function    Hours
1   20121201    Reporting   2
1   20121201    Admin   3
1   20121201    Sales Calls 5
1   20121201    Training    10
**Rates**
CustomerID  AccountRate OperationRates
1   $18     $50

**CALCULATION** - > (OrderCount*AccountRate) + ((Reporting Hours + Admin Hours + Sales Calls Hours) * OperationRates)
**EXAMPLE for customerID 1 on 20121201** -> (20*18) + ((2+3+5) * 50) = $860
    ** Notice that the Hours for Training are not included as the only hours that I care about is Reporting + Admin + Sales Calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that following column combinations are unique: MonthlyOrder[CustomerID,DateID], HoursSpend[CustomerID,DateID,Function], Rates[CustomerID]
you could use something like:

```
select mo.CustomerID, mo.DateID, mo.OrderCount*max(AccountRate) +
        (sum(rep.hours)+sum(adm.hours)+sum(sc.hours))*max(rt.OperationRates)
from MonthlyOrder as mo
  join Rates as rt                on rt.CustomerID = mo.CustomerID
  left join HoursSpend as rep     on rep.CustomerID = mo.CustomerID and
                                     rep.DateId = mo.DateId and
                                     rep.Function = 'Reporting'
  left join HoursSpend as adm     on adm.CustomerID = mo.CustomerID and
                                     adm.DateId = mo.DateId and
                                     adm.Function = 'Admin'
  left join HoursSpend as sc      on sc.CustomerID = mo.CustomerID and
                                     sc.DateId = mo.DateId and
                                     sc.Function = 'Sales Calls'
group by mo.CustomerID, mo.DateID, mo.OrderCount
```